# Is it bad to string interpolate into an SQL query even in a safe context?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-injection

I know that string interpolation can expose you to SQL injection, so you'd never want to do something like this:

```
user_input = params[:event_type]
Event.where("event.type = #{user_input}")
```

But what about using interpolation in a non-user-input context in the interest of code readability? Something like this:

```
class City
  has_many :events

  def important_events
    big = "event.type = 1"
    vip = "organizer.status > 10"

    events.joins(:organizers)
          .where("#{big} OR #{vip}")
  end
end
```

Is this a bad idea? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: That’s fine. Both clause literals are fixed so there is no way to inject something.

Comment: What will happens if another developer must make changes to your code and put some user params into your `big` and `vip` vars. If you want something readable get rid of those vars `events.joins(:organizers).where('event.type = ? AND organizer.status >?', 10)`

Comment: @Octopus-Paul You're probably right. What I'd really like to do though is `events.joins(:organizers).select('events.*').select('organizers.status').where( type: 1 || status: (11..Infinity) )` but that just isn't in the syntactical cards. Oh well. Thanks for chiming in.

Comment: `.where( type: 1 || status: (11..Infinity) )` won’t work as expected. Either use `.where("event.type = 1 OR organizer.status > 10")` or use Arel and something like `.where(Event.arel_table[:type].eq(1).or(Organizer.arel_table[:status].gt(10)))`. There is also [MetaWhere](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/meta_where), which may be more like what you want: `.where((:event => {:type => 1}) | (:organizers => {:status.gt => 10}))`.